# Zoomable shiny plot using POSIXct date ranges

Tags: r, datetime, zooming, shiny

I am trying to amend my shiny code so that my plot is made zoomable.

The problem is, my x axis uses `as.POSIXct` dates as their limits.

For example, a working version of the current app is:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "data",label="Make a choice", choices=c("A","B")), 
                plotOutput("plot1"),dateInput(inputId = "lowerlimit", label="Lower Date",value="2016-01-01"), dateInput(inputId = "upperlimit",label="Upper Date"))

server <- function(input,output){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00",tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2016-06-01 23:45:00",tz="UTC"),by="15 min")
    values=rnorm(14688)
    data=data.frame(Date=dates,Data=values)
    ggplot(data, aes(Date, Data))+geom_line()+
      scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct(input$lowerlimit), as.POSIXct(input$upperlimit)), labels = date_format("%d-%m-%y"))+ylab("")+
      ggtitle("My Plot")+xlab("")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

However, I want to make `plot1` zoomable. I have been trying to follow this [example](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/105-plot-interaction-zoom/) but since my x axis using dates, it does not seem to work.

I have tried:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "data",label="Make a choice", choices=c("A","B")), 
                plotOutput("plot1",dblclick = "plot1_dblclick", brush = brushOpts(id="plot1_brush",resetOnNew = T)),
                dateInput(inputId = "lowerlimit", label="Lower Date",value="2016-01-01"), 
                dateInput(inputId = "upperlimit",label="Upper Date"))

server <- function(input,output){

  ranges <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    if (!is.null(ranges$x)) {
      ranges$x <- as.POSIXct(ranges$x, format = "%d-%m-%y",tz="UTC")
    }

    dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00",tz="UTC"), as.POSIXct("2016-06-01 23:45:00",tz="UTC"),by="15 min")
    values=rnorm(14688)
    data=data.frame(Date=dates,Data=values)

    ggplot(data, aes(Date, Data))+geom_line()+
      scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct(input$lowerlimit), as.POSIXct(input$upperlimit)), labels = date_format("%d-%m-%y"))+ylab("")+
      ggtitle("My Plot")+xlab("")
  })
  observeEvent(input$plot1_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot1_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

    } else {
      ranges$x <- NULL
      ranges$y <- NULL
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

But I get an error which says **"Origin must be supplied"**. 
I know that I have still got my `lowerlimit` and `upperlimit` as the `scale_x_datetime` arguments, but I still want this to be the case, and the axis limits change only when a portion of the plot has been selected to zoom into.

Comment: See  the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34061037/9300556 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118939/9300556

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try dygraph to plot with xaxis zoom

https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
ui <- fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "data",label="Make a choice",         choices=c("A","B")), 
            dygraphOutput("plot1")
)
server <- function(input,output){
  output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({


data=as.ts(rnorm(14688),start="2016-01-01" ,end=  "2016-06-01") 

dygraph(data) %>% dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("2016-01-01",  "2016-06-01 23:45:00"))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I'll have a look at `dygraph` - Thanks. (I'll have to find a way to enable my date ranges to work, since this seems to produce a straight line graph when I use it...)

Comment: Thank you for looking at this, but it seems I cannot pass change my data format to a time series, since it also contains other data columns (grouping IDs). Are you aware of any method which uses `ggplot2`?

Comment: That was what I used to create my attempt in the question.